# How do you use the string class in a source file?

Tags: c++, string

I am currently working on a c++ program with multiple files. (A main file, a header, and a source file)

I have included the string class in my files, yet my program is not compiling. It is giving me errors, saying that string is undefined, but I have clearly included it. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop, if you need to know.

Here are my files:

main.cpp:

```
#include "myClass.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    myClass myObject;
    cout << myObject.helloWorld() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

myClass.h:

```
#include <string>
class myClass {
public:
    string helloWorld();
};
```

myClass.cpp:

```
#include "myClass.h"
#include <string>
string myClass::helloWorld(){
    string str = "Hello World!\n";
    return str;
}
```

I have looked online, but have found nothing. I looked at the following links, if you would like to look:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

http://www.sjbaker.org/wiki/index.php?title=C%2B%2B:_multiple_source_files

Thanks in advance!

P.S. It would be great to know how to manipulate strings in a source file, in general.

Comment: _"I have looked online, but have found nothing"_ I do not believe you. This is asked all the time. Heck, the first few paragraphs of the chapter in your C++ book about strings _must_ explain how to use it properly.

Comment: Haven't found it. Plus, I completely forgot about std::

Comment: `using namespace std;` is [poor style](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/Coding-standards#using-namespace-std). Replace all your `string` with `std::string` and `cout` with `std::cout`.

Comment: @WhiteViking According to cplusplus.com, it speeds up compile time. But that article does have a point...

Comment: @FlareCat can you give a link? I would be surprised if cplusplus.com claims that this would speed up compile time, but if they do i would like to read it

Comment: _"it speeds up compile time"_ Complete nonsense. If anything you'd be slowing down the build (but I can't imagine it'd ever be noticeable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the type is `std::string`. Write it out in full, without shortcuts.